# vairable name as value of another variable, ASP classic

Tags: function, variables, asp-classic, return-value

i would like to make a function that takes the variable name as a string, check if exist a querystring, or a request.form or a variable with that name and return the value.

```
function revalue(varName)

   if request(varName) <> "" then
        revalue= request(varName)
    else        
        revalue= "" 
    end if

end function
```

how can i check if the variable called as the value of `varName` exist and has a value?

Comment: Why? This function does exactly the same thing as Request(varname)...

Comment: @RicoSuave you're missing the part where they say "or a variable."  I have to admit i scratched my head at this one for a few minutes as well.  I just hope that they are not using user input for that eval they are using in the answer.

Comment: well, ok, you have to read carefully to get the sense of this, but the idea was to make a function that recompile all the form textboxes, but the value could be in another form, or a session, or a variable or in the database. the values come from a user form, i know that there could be a lot of dirty inputs, but this script will run in a private lan, so the uesrs will be really few, and all traceable :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...

```
else
   if eval(varName) <> "" then
     revalue= eval(varName)
   else
     revalue= ""    
   end if
end if
```